# Python base64 data decode and byte order convert

Tags: python, base64, byte

I am now using python base64 module to decode a base64 coded XML file, what I did was to find each of the data (there are thousands of them as for exmaple in "ABC....", the "ABC..." was the base64 encoded data) and add it to a string, lets say s, then I use base64.b64decode(s) to get the result, I am not sure of the result of the decoding, was it a string, or bytes? In addition, how should convert such decoded data from the so-called "network byte order" to a "host byte order"? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Each base64 encoded string should be decoded separately - you can't concatenate encoded strings (and get a correct decoding).
The result of the decode is a string, of byte-buffer - in Python, they're equivalent.
Regarding the network/host order - sequences of bytes, have no such 'order' (or endianity) - it only matters when interpreting these bytes as words / ints of larger width (i.e. more than 8 bits).

Comment: Thanks! Yes, I think my process is : find one encoded data, then add it to an empty string, then decode it, hold the result to a container, say a list; then empty the string and find the next encoded data, does that make sense please?

Comment: This seems reasonable, although if you post some more information (e.g. some of your code, what your XML file looks like, etc.) you'll get better answers.

Comment: I dont know how to give it a right format. The data are too large
 to be fully post here, however, I kept the original format of how 
it looks like. There are typically thousands of "scan" which looks 
like this in the XML file, the data is "Q5YACqAAAA....."

Answer (score 2):

Base64 stuff, encoded or not, is stored in strings.  Byte order is only an issue if you're dealing with non-characters (C's int, short, long, float, etc.), and then I'm not sure how it would relate to this issue.  Also, I don't think concatenating base64-encoded strings is valid.

```
>>> from base64 import *
>>> b64encode( "abcdefg" )
'YWJjZGVmZw=='
>>> b64decode( "YWJjZGVmZw==" )
'abcdefg'
>>> b64encode( "hijklmn" )
'aGlqa2xtbg=='
>>> b64decode( "aGlqa2xtbg==" )
'hijklmn'
>>> b64decode( "YWJjZGVmZw==aGlqa2xtbg==" )
'abcdefg'
>>> b64decode( "YWJjZGVmZwaGlqa2xtbg==" )
'abcdefg\x06\x86\x96\xa6\xb6\xc6\xd6\xe0'
```

Comment: Yes, I see your example, it would not work with concatenating a string as they got certain formats. I copied one data completely(thousands of them in one XML file) into a text file and decoded by a web base64 decoder, the result is a bin file. what should I do if I would like to know what is it within this encoded data please?

Answer (score 1):

This guy has a good python based
b64decode parser http://groups.google.com/group/spctools-discuss/browse_thread/thread/a8afd04e1a04cde4

Extracting peak-lists from mzXML in "Python"